# How can I modify this script to update Taxonomy Fields in SharePoint 2010 with a CSV?

Tags: powershell, csv, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Here is the script I have so far. I know it is close. I am trying to update a list of items using a csv file. I cannot however update the Taxonomy field. I am trying to avoid requiring the guid and term ID for it to run.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction Inquire


#Read the CSV file 
$CSVData = Import-CSV -path "C:\files\testimport.csv" 
#Get the Web
$web = Get-SPWeb -identity "http://site/Policies/"
$web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true;

Write-Host ( $web.Lists | Format-Table | Out-String)
#Get the Target List
$list = $web.Lists["Documents"]

$item = $list.GetItemById(4)
#$newTerm = "Test Data|074bbed9-da60-4a0c-9691-344436b5f96a"


$metadataField = ($item["Metadata"] -as       [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection])
#$metadataValue = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection -ArgumentList ""
#$metadataValue.PopulateFromLabelGuidPair("TestData");
#$metadataField.Add($metadataValue);

forEach ($line in $CSVData){
$item["Department"] = $($line.Department);
$item["Topics"] = $($line.Topics);
$item["History"] = $($line.History);
$metadataField = "Test Program|074bbed9-da60-4a0c-9691-344436b5f96a";
```

}

```
Write-Host ($item | Format-List | Out-String) 
Write-Host ($metadata | Format-List | Out-String)
$item.Update();
#$list.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the reference to the term and then set the value of the taxonomy field using TaxonomyField.SetFieldValue method. Please refer to this article for more details - [Updating SharePoint Managed Metadata Columns with PowerShell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/02/15/updating-sharepoint-managed-metadata-columns-with-powershell.aspx)